# Functions included from the prototype in a javascript class are not seen in the editor's autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dynamic-import

I have the following problem, I have created a library. which its methodos
they are in separate files `writeLog.js` in a folder called `./lib`.
and I have an `index.js` file that explores that folder and extracts the function
and puts the same name as the file as the function name.

example: 
`writeLog.js`

and then I can use

```js
    let jsPackTools require('./index');
        let utils = new jsPackTools();
        utils.writeLog('test');
```

The way I use to add the methods to the classes is through the prototype.
the folder is scanned with readdirSync () and then I take the file name to
place it inside a require ().

the code is the following:

```js
   fs.readdirSync(__dirname+'/lib').forEach(modules => {
        let module = modules.split('.').shift();
        jsPackTools.prototype[module] =require(\`${__dirname}/lib/${module}\`);
    });
```

Everything works perfectly fine, the problem is that when I want to access my methods through the autocomplete of any code editor. Methods they seem to be not accessible. however everything works perfectly, I can do use of functions.

The **problem** is that I have to know each method that I am going to use and **it cannot be visualized in the completed auto of any editor**.

I have tried with:

```js
   const writeLog = require('./lib/writeLog');

    class jsPackTools {
       get writeLog() { return writeLog.bind(this) }
    }
```

This allows indexing perfectly. however, I don't logo do it dynamically.

The idea is that the class does not know what its methods are until the **./lib** folder is scanned and all methods are extracted. This way you can add functions inderteminately and when you use them you can see.
    
I do not want to use transpilators, I thought of using a d.ts but it is necessary to use typeScript but the intention is to create this library without dependencies or the least possible.

Comment: Dynamic requires are bad for many reasons, autocomplete being just one of them (breaking bundlers is another, and more important). Don't do that. `require` what you need explicitly. There aren't thousands of modules in your lib anyways.

Comment: "*I do not want to use transpilators*" - if you don't want to use static code generation, but do your "code generation" at runtime dynamically, then there's no way any autocomplete could know about this. What editor are you even using - the answer might depend quite a lot on that?

Comment: Like Georg said, just don't do that. And if you really insist on having individual methods in individual files (which, tbh, to me just suggests that the methods and your class are too large), don't use an `index.js` file that dynamically explores the folder when your library loads, but rather have a build step that explores your folder and automatically generates an appropriate `index.js` file that has explicit dependencies and assignments.